# sqlite3 raised an error after running Airflow command line

Tags: sqlite, airflow

When I ran command: airflow list_users
It raised an error as below:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: ab_permission_view_role

...

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: 
ab_permission_view_role [SQL: 'SELECT ab_permission_view_role.id AS 
ab_permission_view_role_id, ab_permission_view_role.permission_view_id AS ab_permission_view_role_permission_view_id, ab_permission_view_role.role_id AS 
ab_permission_view_role_role_id \nFROM ab_permission_view_role JOIN 
ab_permission_view ON ab_permission_view.id = 
ab_permission_view_role.permission_view_id JOIN ab_view_menu ON ab_view_menu.id = ab_permission_view.view_menu_id \nWHERE ab_permission_view_role.role_id = ? 
AND ab_permission_view.view_menu_id != ?'] [parameters: (4, 51)] (Background on 
this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

There is also the same error after running: airflow create_user

Comment: Did you run [`airflow initdb`](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#initdb) / [`airflow upgradedb`](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#upgradedb) command after installing / configuring a new meta-db for your Airflow deployment?

Comment: yes,I ran the two commands, but it still didn't work with the same error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[**Airflow v1**] This happened because ab_* tables were not created at `airflow initdb`. All these tables are for Role-based-access-control – RBAC.

To have these tables, follow the instructions:

```
edit airflow.cfg

[webserver]
rbac = True
```

and run `airflow initdb` to create these missed tables.

Comment: you might try `airflow db init` in version 2.1.2

Answer (score 11):

In addition to the answer by Newton Jose, after editing the cfg file, start the webserver using

```
airflow webserver
```

Then open another terminal, switch to your working directory and run

```
airflow initdb
```

You can now start your scheduler

```
airflow scheduler
```

The bottomline is that your webserver should be running when you run the command for initializing the database. Atleast, that is what worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to perform initialization after installation:

```
$ export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
$ airflow initdb
```

If `AIRFLOW_HOME` is unset, `~/airflow/` will be created and used. This is where the config and logs will be stored; if you want to reset the configuration, remove the dir stored in `AIRFLOW_HOME` and rerun `airflow initdb`.

Now other commands should work, e.g.

```
$ airflow version
[2019-08-15 22:39:34,673] {__init__.py:51} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/  v1.10.4
```

Source: [Installation](https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html) section from `airflow` docs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error even after I had initialized the db; I could go on my webserver, run `airflow db shell`, and see that the tables actually existed. In my case it was because I was launching Airflow from docker-compose and had just added an environment variable to my docker-compose.yml:

```
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    environment:
      MY_ENV_VAR: 100
```

By specifying an environment variable, I overrode the environment variables from my `airflow-common` alias -- including

```
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
```

This caused my Airflow workers to restart as soon as they tried the `celery worker` command. That was the ultimate source of the "no such table" errors. I resolved this by defining and including an alias just for those shared env variables:

```
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
  ...
    <<: *airflow-common
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      MY_ENV_VAR: 100
```